# Does C# support procedures?

Tags: c#

I just want to know if C# supports procedures? I tried to figure it out by myself, but there is nothing about procedures in C#.

Comment: Do you mean sql stored procedure ?

Comment: Title asks about C#, body asks about C.  What doe you want?  This is unclear

Comment: or Pascal procedure?

Answer (score 1):

A procedure is a set of command which can be executed in order. it may be or may be not have return value. You can use c# methods, read [Methods (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx)